# Do Some Commands Depends on picture's Width and Height

Tags: windows, batch-file

the code below will extract width and height of pictures in a root directory.

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
(for /r %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%b in ('"MEDIAINFO --INFORM=Image;%%Width%%:%%Height%% "%%~a""') do (
        echo(%%b %%~c)
))
pause
```

[MediaInfo CLI version](http://mediaarea.net/us/MediaInfo/Download/Windows)

%%b and %%~c will store width and height, as you can see in code there is no %%~c variable but it still is working. I want to do the commands below:

```
after getting width and height with above code
if width>height
   w=width-100
   resize picture /width=w
else 
   h=height-100
   resize picture /height=h
```

I will do resizing with a cmd utility, but the problem is assigning %%b and %%~c to two variables and comparing them with eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
set "MI=U:\scripts\utilities\Mediainfo\Mediainfo.exe"
for /r %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%b in ('"%MI% --INFORM=Image;%%Width%%:%%Height%% "%%~a""') do (
        echo(%%b %%c
        if %%b GTR %%c (
          set /a w=%%b-100
          Echo resize picture /width=!w!
        ) ELSE (
          set /a h=%%c-100
          Echo  resize picture /height=!h!
        )         
    )
)

pause
```

Comment: it will give "Missing Operand" error, there is something wrong with %%b and %%~c, it seems then can not be compare to assign to a variable and I do not know why :(

Comment: Nice work Matt, with your edit, it is now working like a charm ;)